# django :how to configure celery redis

Tags: django, redis, celery

According to celery using redis docs

**Configuration**

```
Configuration is easy, just configure the location of your Redis database:

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

Where the URL is in the format of:

redis://:password@hostname:port/db_number

all fields after the scheme are optional, and will default to localhost on port 6379, using database 0.
```

Where can i find this configuration file. Is this in setting.py of my project.

Comment: Yes, it is settings.py

Comment: I'm pretty disappointed how unclear this is in the Celery docs.